# listview filter suddenly broken

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview displaying contacts. 
Initially I display all contacts.
When I start typing the list goes blank, regardless of what I type.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    fillContacts();
    contactList.setAdapter(geoAdapter);
    ...
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable str) {
            geoAdapter.getFilter().filter(str, new Filter.FilterListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFilterComplete(int i) {
                geoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
}
```